# continuous time quantum walk on a cycle - transition matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, quantum-walks

I am trying to find the transition matrix for a quantum walk on a cycle.
The vertices are labelled $\lbrace 0,1,2,\ldots,n-1\rbrace$, where vertex $i$ is a neighbour of vertex $i \pm 1$.
Lets say we start at vertex 0. Then we are interested in $\langle i \vert U(t) \vert 0 \rangle$.

I have calculated the following:
The normalized adjacency matrix for A is a circulant matrix, hence (normalized) eigenvectors and eigenvalues are
$$v_j= \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\left( \omega_j^0, \omega_j^1,\ldots,\omega_j^{n-1}\right) \text{ and }\\ \lambda_j= \cos(2 \pi j / n),  \hspace{2cm} \text{ respecively.}$$.

Thus, $U(t)= \exp(iAt)= \sum\limits_{j=1}^n\exp(i t \lambda_j ) v_j v_j^\dagger$.

This gives,

$$ \langle i \vert U(t) \vert 0 \rangle = \langle i \vert \sum\limits_{j=1}^n\exp(i t \lambda_j ) v_j v_j^\dagger \vert 0 \rangle  $$
$$ = \sum\limits_{j=1}^n \exp(i t \lambda_j ) \langle i \vert  v_j v_j^\dagger \vert 0 \rangle $$
$$ = \sqrt{\dfrac{1}{n}}\sum\limits_{j=1}^n \exp(i t \lambda_j ) \langle i \vert  v_j  \rangle $$
$$ ={\dfrac{1}{n}}\sum\limits_{j=1}^n \exp(i t \lambda_j )\ \   {\omega_j}^{i}$$.

Is this calculation correct?
Is there a way to further simplify this?

Is there another way to get compact expression (in terms of t) for the matrix $U(t)$?

Comment: To clarify, you don't have a Hadamard coin here, and you are just evolving unitarily according to the Hamiltonian by $e^{-iAt}$, right?  Here you are asking for transition probability (transition amplitude) of evolving from node $0$ to node $i$ at time $t$, right?  Classically walking on a cycle you get to the uniform distribution in roughly $\mathcal{O}(\sqrt n)$ time

Comment: @Yes. That is correct. We have the standard definition of continuous time quantum walk.

Answer (score 1):

(Not much of an answer yet, just some tentative ideas about how to simulate a continuous-time random walk on a cycle for now.  I describe how to take a small quantum walk for a short amount of time, but I'm otherwise getting stuck.)

Recall that the cycle graph on $n$ vertices is isomorphic to the Cayley graph of the additive group $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ with generators $\pm 1$, which is isomorphic to the rotations of the $n$-gon with clockwise or right $R$ and counterclockwise or left $L$ rotations.

We'll start off with $n=4$ for simplicity and convenience.  We have $n=4$ qubits labeled $\{|0\rangle,|1\rangle,|2\rangle,|3\rangle\}$, and we can use the following SWAP circuits that perform the rotations:

[image: SWAP circuits]

There's nothing quantum about this circuit yet, but we can use phase estimation to take the roots of each of $L$ and $R$, as we know that the eigenvalues of $R$ and $L$ are $\{\pm 1, \pm i\}$ because $L^4=R^4=I$.  These eigenvalues correspond to the $\lambda_j$ in the question.

Letting $|\psi\rangle$ be the wavefunction for registers $|0\rangle|1\rangle|2\rangle|3\rangle$, below are the $4$-th root of $R$  and $L$:

[image: Fourth Roots of Rotations]

It's the *fourth* root in particular because of the $T=\sqrt[4]Z$ and $S=\sqrt[2]Z$ gates in the middle of the circuit - if we want a smaller movement corresponding to a larger root, we'd use other roots of $Z$.  Let's call this power the Trotter factor.  As this factor increases to infinity, I think we're approaching continuous-time evolution.

We can go back and forth between the $r$th root of a clockwise right rotation and a counterclockwise left rotation.  An iteration would be:

$$\sqrt[4]{R}\sqrt[4]{L}\sqrt[4]{R}\sqrt[4]{L}\sqrt[4]{R}\sqrt[4]{L}\sqrt[4]{R}\sqrt[4]{L}\cdots$$

I'd like to get this to be a continuous-time quantum walk, corresponding to a little walk to the right (clockwise), then a walk to the left (counterclockwise), then... etc.  But, this ends up being the identity after only two repetitions, I think.  Either I'm doing something wrong (highly likely), or such a walk on the graph cycles quickly back and forth between the identity, perhaps?

Comment: Thanks for your answer but here I am more interested in the transition probabilities rather than the actual circuit or implementation. What I am looking for is the probability that quantum walk is at vertex j at time t. I have included a calculation in the question, I want to know a) if it is correct b) Is there a way to further simplify this>

Comment: @Root have you thought about explicitly working out $U(t)$ for small $n$, such as $n=4$?